# Point outside of projection domain (2050) Error

Tags: postgis

I have an intermittent issue with my application stemming from a PostGIS error.

Randomly during normal operations (sometimes weeks at a time without issue), every ST_Buffer invocation results in the following message.

```
[1064] ERROR:  transform: Point outside of projection domain (2050)
[1064] CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_buffer" statement 1
[1064] STATEMENT:  SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Buffer(CAST($1 AS geography), $2, 'quad_segs=8')) AS geojson
[1064] ERROR:  transform: Point outside of projection domain (2050)
```

Any time calling ST_Buffer from the point where this error appears, ALL addition requests result in the same error, grinding the application to a half. This is resolved by restarting the database.

What's the root reason for this message? Googling seems to show it exists across many GIS applications, but no real info seems to exist on what it means.

Validated this occurs when buffering a single point at Lng/Lat 0,0, where there should be no buffer issues.

Versions:

PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

PostGIS 3.1.3

Comment: Please provide what version the Postgres Db and which POSTGIS_FULL_VERSION you are running.

Comment: I suspect the ST_BUFFER() of the 'Null Island' location might create some sort of 'zero lock' wherein coordinates can be offset, but not stitched into a polygon across the meridians.  Can you confirm any other Lat/Lon location where this consistently occurs?

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

PostGIS 3.1.3

I can dig in and try to find a place where this consistently happens

Comment: Is the resulting SQL request logically like this `SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Buffer(CAST(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT (0 0)') AS geography), 1000, 'quad_segs=8')) AS geojson`?

Comment: [This error comes from PROJ](https://proj.org/development/reference/datatypes.html#c.PROJ_ERR_COORD_TRANSFM_OUTSIDE_PROJECTION_DOMAIN) (coordinate projection / transform library).

"Coordinate is outside of the projection domain. e.g. approximate mercator with |longitude - lon_0| > 90°, or iterative convergence method failed."

Perhaps you have data in two different coordinate reference systems and when converting between them one or more coordinates fall outside of the projection domain?